# Running webdriver.io on vsts/Tfs build

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, tfs, azure-pipelines

I have some webdriver.io tests, and the current build system we use is not jenkins, but microsoft Tfs or vsts. Is there a way to run these on that build system as part of Continuous integration and continuous deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your webdriverio is using javascript(mocha framework), on Azure DevOps (same as old TFS), Create a new pipeline to run NodeJS, follow these steps in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops

With just a pipeline, I can run my webdriverio mocha-framework tests on the microsoft vm already without setting up extra build environment.

Next, you can add a trigger to your pipeline so it will get kicked off after another pipeline build complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Selenium tests in Node.js with WebDriverIO. Then It should be same with the standard Selenium testing, see [Get started with Selenium testing in a CD pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=vsts) for details.

Below articles for your reference:

- [Setting up Selenium tests with Webdriver.io](https://medium.com/@boriscoder/setting-up-selenium-tests-with-webdriver-io-cc7fc3c86629)
- [How to write Selenium tests in Node.js with WebDriverIO](https://buddy.works/guides/how-write-selenium-tests-in-nodejs-with-webdriver)